# Unexpected XML processing instruction in JSF 2.2 generated HTML

Tags: html, jsf, netbeans, glassfish-4, mojarra

In a sample JSF project created with NetBeans 7.4 and deployed on GlassFish 4.0 / Mojarra 2.2.0, the generated HTML contains a XML processing instruction, `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>`, in the first line:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
        <title>Facelet Title</title></head><body>
        Hello from Facelets
    </body>
</html>
```

The JSF page source is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
    </h:body>
</html>the
```

The W3 HTML validator complains that the HTML is invalid, XML processing instruction are not supported in HTML.

I encountered the problem first in a NetBeans 8.0.2 / GlassFish 4.1 environment and now tried to reproduce it with older versions (and fresh installation) of the components.

Could this a configuration mistake or maybe a bug?

The web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How do you see it is invalid? NetBeans is merely an IDE which itself does nothing like compiling/validating something.

Comment: @Tiny - on https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input  I enter the HTML5 source and the validator says that the validator encountered an error: `XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML`